# unable to group the field with same item_hsn and sum the quantity of it using group by sql statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

```
Select purchase_items.item_hsn, sales_items.item_hsn, purchase_items.quantity as qty1,
      sales_items.quantity as 'qty2', 
      purchase_items.quantity-sales_items.quantity as 'Difference'
  from purchase_items 
  LEFT JOIN sales_items ON purchase_items.item_hsn = sales_items.item_hsn;
```

Here this is my query i have two tables purchase_items and sales_items i want to generate the stock of items with respect to item_hsn and its quantity

```
stock=purchase-sales;
```

Unable to do so i am a newbie out here please help me out with this:

[image: 1]

I have added the output its getting confused with two same item_hsn with different quantities.

Comment: the output i want is group of item_hsn with sum of their quantity from both the tables and difference between both the quantites

Comment: Sample data would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"Select purchase_items.item_hsn, purchase_items.item_name, sales_items.item_hsn, (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM purchase_items
WHERE purchase_items.item_hsn=sales_items.item_hsn) as 'qty2', (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM sales_items WHERE purchase_items.item_hsn=sales_items.item_hsn)
as 'qty1' ,(SELECT sum(quantity) FROM purchase_items WHERE purchase_items.item_hsn=sales_items.item_hsn) - (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM sales_items WHERE
purchase_items.item_hsn=sales_items.item_hsn) as 'Difference' from purchase_items,sales_items WHERE purchase_items.item_hsn = sales_items.item_hsn
GROUP BY purchase_items.item_hsn, sales_items.item_hsn"


**here is the query for stock**
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select 
    i.item_hsn, 
    sum(i.quantity) as qty1, 
    coalesce(sum(s.quantity), 0) as qty2, 
    sum(i.quantity) - coalesce(sum(s.quantity), 0) - s.quantity as diff
from purchase_items i
left join sales_items s on p.item_hsn = s.item_hsn
group by i.item_hsn
```

Notes:

- `coalesce()` ensures that we get proper results for items that have no sales
- Don't use single quotes for identifiers; they should be used for literal strings only. Instead, use backticks, or better yet use unquoted identifiers.

Comment: thanks for your responses guyz but i have got it right with some effort here is the query

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your underlying tables have multiple rows per item hsn.  This suggests a different approach for the aggregation.  I would use `union all` to restructure the data and then aggregate:

```
select item_hsn, sum(purchases) as purchases, sum(sales) as sales,
       sum(purchases) - sum(sales) as difference
from ((select pi.ite_hsn, pi.quantity as purchases, 0 as sales
       from purchase_items pi
      ) union all
      (select si.ite_hsn, 0 as purchases, si.quantity as sales
       from sales_items si
      )
     ) ps
group by item_hsn
```

I'm not sure where the item name is coming from.  It is not being returned by the query you have written.  But you should be able to tweak this query to include it.